# Why is Nevada so slow to count the vote for the 2020 election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, nevada

I've been watching the results come in at the [Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/trump-biden-election-day-2020), and I've noticed Nevada is unbelievably slow at counting.  By my estimate, only 11% was counted in the last 24 hours.

What's up with this?

Comment: Keep in mind that the slowness of vote counting may be a bit worse than normal, but not by that much. Usually the election isn't close enough that it matters so one candidate or the other concedes well before the counting is done. Part of the "slowness" is just that it is more obvious when it holds up the final result.

Comment: Nevada allows same-day voter registration, which means a massive number of provisional ballots that must be cured before they can be counted. Curing those ballots is even slower than validating mail ballots, some of which *also* need to be cured.

Comment: Similar question: [Why has the state of Arizona taken so long to return results in the 2020 US Presidential Election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59996/12081)

Answer (score 5):

The reason Nevada is slow at counting is that Nevada mostly received mailed ballots, which take a lot of time to count as people feared the pandemic

**CNN:** https://edition.cnn.com/2020/11/05/politics/vote-count-key-states/index.html

> It's hard to determine how many ballots are outstanding in Nevada because the state is one of a handful that mailed ballots to all active registered voters. Election officials will count mail-in ballots received through November 10, as long as they were postmarked by Election Day.

**Metro Uk:** https://metro.co.uk/2020/11/06/why-is-nevada-taking-so-long-to-count-their-us-election-2020-votes-13547155/

> Nevada is taking so long to count its votes because of the surge in the number of people opting for mail-in voting. People were less inclined to physically go to polling stations to cast their votes this year for fears they could catch the coronavirus.